# Which cygwin package contains the rm command?

Tags: cygwin

I installed a minimal version of cygwin, but i now need to install the rm command.

Which cygwin package contains the rm command ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must have a very minimal Cygwin install. rm is usually contained inside coreutils.

Comment: I installed OpenSSH for Windows, it installs just enough to get ssh running.  http://sourceforge.net/projects/opensshwindows/

Answer (score 1):

It should be in the `coreutils` package.  I haven't used Cygwin in a long time, but if it hasn't updated to `coreutils` yet, try finding a `fileutils` package.  That is rather dated though, considering the fact that the pages on the GNU site for the `fileutils`, `sh-utils`/`shellutils` and `textutils` packages all refer you to the `coreutils` page.